# How to fix Xcode issue BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug

Tags: xcode, flutter

When I try to launch my flutter app on my iphone I have this error...

I try all stackoverflow solutions :

```
-Build Active Architecture Only to NO 
-Remove flutter.framework and APP.framework
-flutter clean 
-Xcode 11.4 migration
```

Here is my error :(

```
=== BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
Target 'Pods-Runner' of project 'Pods' was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'Pods_Runner.framework' because its architectures 'arm64' didn't contain all required architectures 'armv7 arm64'
```

Comment: had you resolved this issue?

Comment: Not exactly I have always this error or part of this error with my original projet I have create before catalina xcode 11.5 and last flutter upgrade, but when I create a new projet after all these upgrade, I havn't this error....